# How to extract data from .ini file in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, ini, converters

I have daily temperature data stored in ini files. I need to read these data using r to create a time series. I used ini package to read data but data in a list. I need to extract only temperature data in between * characters.

I used unlist() function and data.frame() but could not get data frame with temperature data.

```
library(ini)

filename="C:/Research/Time_series/WT/2018/01/RAWWT20180101.ini"
# https://www.dropbox.com/s/vyinidvs947mw9g/RAWWT20180101.ini?dl=0

data <- read.ini(filename, encoding = getOption("encoding"))
str(data)
List of 1
 $ Historical Data:List of 25
  ..$ 00H: chr "* 29.7  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.7  29.8  29.8  29.7  29.7  29.7  29.7  29.7  29.7  29.7  29.7  29.7  29.7  29.7  29.7 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 01H: chr "* 29.6  29.6  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.6  29.6  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.6  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 02H: chr "* 29.4  29.4  29.4  29.3  29.3  29.4  29.3  29.3  29.3  29.4  29.3  29.3  29.3  29.3  29.3  29.4  29.3  29.3  29.3  29.3  29.3 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 03H: chr "* 29.2  29.2  29.3  29.2  29.2  29.2  29.2  29.2  29.2  29.2  29.2  29.2  29.2  29.2  29.2  29.2  29.2  29.2  29.1  29.2  29.1 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 04H: chr "* 29.2  29.2  29.1  29.2  29.1  29.2  29.2  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.2  29.2  29.1  29.2  29.2  29.1  29.2  29.2  29.1  29.1 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 05H: chr "* 29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 06H: chr "* 29.1  29.0  29.0  29.0  29.1  29.0  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.0  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.0  29.1  29.1  29.0  29.0  29.0 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 07H: chr "* 29.0  29.0  29.0  29.0  29.0  29.0  29.0  29.0  29.0  29.0  29.0  29.0  29.0  29.0  29.0  28.9  29.0  29.0  29.0  29.0  29.0 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 08H: chr "* 29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 09H: chr "* 29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1  29.1 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 10H: chr "* 29.3  29.3  29.3  29.3  29.3  29.3  29.3  29.3  29.3  29.3  29.3  29.3  29.4  29.4  29.4  29.4  29.4  29.4  29.4  29.4  29.4 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 11H: chr "* 29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5  29.5 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 12H: chr "* 29.6  29.6  29.4  29.3  29.3  29.4  29.4  29.4  29.4  29.4  29.4  29.4  29.4  29.3  29.3  29.3  29.4  29.4  29.4  29.3  29.3 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 13H: chr "* 29.5  29.4  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.4  29.4  29.4  29.4  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.7  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 14H: chr "* 29.9  29.9  29.9  30.0  30.0  30.0  29.9  30.0  30.0  30.0  30.0  30.0  30.0  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.0  30.1  30.0  30.1 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 15H: chr "* 30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.1  30.1  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 16H: chr "* 30.3  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.3  30.3  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2  30.2 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 17H: chr "* 30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1  30.1 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 18H: chr "* 29.9  29.9  29.9  29.9  29.9  29.9  29.9  29.9  29.9  29.9  29.9  29.9  29.9  29.9  29.9  29.9  29.9  29.9  29.9  29.9  29.9 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 19H: chr "* 29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 20H: chr "* 29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 21H: chr "* 29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.7  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.7  29.8  29.7  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 22H: chr "* 29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 23H: chr "* 29.6  29.5  29.6  29.6  29.5  29.5  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.5  29.5  29.6  29.5  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6  29.6 "| __truncated__
  ..$ 24H: chr "* 30.3 1528  28.9 0641*"


s <-unlist(data)

ss <-data.frame(s,,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I need to create output like numeric values as follows.

```
29.7  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.8  29.7  29.8  29.8  29.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this would work?

```
library(ini)

filename<-choose.files()

data <- read.ini(filename, encoding = getOption("encoding")) 
str(data)


s <-unlist(data)

ss <-data.frame(s,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


newdata<-apply(ss,1,function(x){as.numeric(unlist(str_match_all(x,"\\b\\-*\\d+\\.*\\d*\\b")))})

> str(newdata)
List of 25
 $ Historical Data.00H: num [1:60] 29.7 29.8 29.8 29.8 29.8 29.8 29.7 29.8 29.8 29.7 ...
 $ Historical Data.01H: num [1:60] 29.6 29.6 29.5 29.5 29.5 29.6 29.6 29.5 29.5 29.5 ...
```

Comment: I add stringr library to run str_match_all function. Then ns <-data.frame(unlist(newdata),stringsAsFactors=FALSE) to obtain list of all values.

Answer (score 3):

Snippet for reading ini files with just base R:

```
blank = "^\\s*$"
header = "^\\[(.*)\\]$"
key_value = "^.*=.*$"

extract = function(regexp, x) regmatches(x, regexec(regexp, x))[[1]][2]

read_ini = function(fn) {
    lines = readLines(fn)
    ini = list()
    for (l in lines) {
        if (grepl(blank, l)) next
        if (grepl(header, l)) {
            section = extract(header, l)
            ini[[section]] = list()
        }
        if (grepl(key_value, l)) {
            kv = strsplit(l, "\\s*=\\s*")[[1]]
            ini[[section]][[kv[1]]] = kv[2]
        }
    }
    ini
}
```

This will be read into a list of lists, with the section headers as the names of the outer list. The regex functions would be considerably cleaner with `stringr` but I think it's worth the effort for short scripts.